# How can I tell what is different in Compare-Object result?

Tags: powershell, compare

Given the following sample code (Powershell), which is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505244/897326):

```
$newFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -recurse -path "c:\path1");
$oldFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -recurse -path "c:\path2");
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $newFiles -DifferenceObject $oldFiles -Property FullName,Length,LastWriteTime
```

I have `SideIndicator` to tell whether or not an object with the same property set is present in either sides. But this is usually of little use for production purposes. What I really need is key all objects by `FullName` and then compare by `Length` and `LastWriteTime` (for the above example). If different, be able to tell what exactly is different (`Length` or `LastWriteTime` or both), and how exactly (>, <, =). Is it possible with Powershell, using built-in ways?

Comment: Give up and install a sane Gnu `diff.exe` utility. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877238/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-the-diff-command/

Comment: @MarkHu Ha-ha, the post is from 2013, I have given up on Powershell since then. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Compare-Object` is a pretty feature-light cmdlet. It could stand some serious improvements.  The best way I could get this to work was to piece out the removed/added files into a separate bucket and then compare just the same files using `Name` not `FullName` with a `SyncWindow` of 1 e.g.:

```
$removed = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $oldFiles -DifferenceObject $newFiles -Property Name -PassThru | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='}
$added = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $oldFiles -DifferenceObject $newFiles -Property Name -PassThru | Where {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}
$removedNames = $removed | Foreach {$_.Fullname}
$same = $oldFiles | Where {$_.Fullname -notin $removedNames}
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $same -DifferenceObject $newFiles -Property Name,Length,LastWriteTime -SyncWindow 1
```

This gave me results like this:

```
Name                                                 Length LastWriteTime                 SideIndicator
----                                                 ------ -------------                 -------------
AssemblyInfo.Shared.cs                                  340 8/28/2012 1:21:53 AM          =>
AssemblyInfo.Shared.cs                                  340 8/28/2012 1:21:28 AM          <=
EchoArgs.cs                                             825 8/28/2012 1:21:54 AM          =>
EchoArgs.cs                                             825 8/28/2012 1:21:30 AM          <=
AssemblyInfo.cs                                         151 8/28/2012 1:21:54 AM          =>
AssemblyInfo.cs                                         151 8/28/2012 1:21:31 AM          <=
```

Even so, part way through the listing the files get out of sync.  Go figure.  If you eliminate the SyncWindow parameter, you still get "correct" results it is just that the files are scattered about and not lined up one under another.  :-(

Comment: +1. How does SyncWindow work? What if it's set to 2,3,etc.? I found little documentation about it on the net.

Comment: It is supposed to tell PowerShell how far (as in indices into the Ref/Diff object arrays) to search for a matching object in order to re-sync.  The default is [int32]::maxvalue which gives it a very wide window - which you would think would be best.  But from playing around with the cmdlet it seemed to match better with a smaller sync window.  I'm not exactly sure why.  :-(

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought, hence the question. Looks like Compare-Object is one of the big mysteries in Powershell. I'll play with your suggestions in a sandbox environment and see if it works for my needs. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: shouldn't you sort the results by your criteria before comparing?

Comment: @x0n tried that and it helped a little but not much.  I was surprised it helped at all since I kind of thought GCI would return files in essentially the same dir structure in the same order.