# Compare-Object on $null array

Tags: object, powershell, compare

Is there a way for the Compare-Object cmdlet to anticipate on $Null values?

For example when I'm trying to compare 2 values like this:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Value1 -DifferenceObject $Value2
```

I commonly get the following error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null
```

My question is: Is there a way to say: if either one of them equals $null ; do something

Comment: Cross posting another answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504346/powershell-compare-object-on-empty-folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Help on Compare-object says:

If the reference set or the difference set is null ($null), Compare-Object generates a terminating error.

So your only options would seem to be a trap or try/catch.

Answer (score 23):

This accepts null values:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject @($Value1 | Select-Object) -DifferenceObject @($Value2 | Select-Object)
```

Comment: This works marvelously for what I was looking for. I'm importing from AD, but if the array is null, I error. I want to get the result that object is different from object2 (null) if that is the case.  This does it in a simple manor without having to write evaluation cases for objects.

Comment: I noticed the pipe to `Select-Object` wasn't necessary in my tests. Can you explain why you used it in your answer?

Comment: @($null).Count
1

@($null | Select-Object).Count
0

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Could you explain why this works? Is it because Select-Object always returns an object whereas e.g. get-content returns a string of bytes?

Answer (score 1):

```
 if($Value1 -eq $NULL){
     return
 }
 Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Value1 -DifferenceObject $Value2
```

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you explain it.

Comment: It's just an alternative to try/catch. If the first value is NULL stop. If isn't NULL, you can Compare the Object. I don't know PS good enough to get those try/catch phrases working.

Answer (score 1):

This does something if null:

```
if ($Value1 -ne $null -and $Value2 -ne $null) {
    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Value1 -DifferenceObject $Value2
}
else {
    #do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround you can use

First, create two empty array object

```
$reference = @()
$difference = @()
```

Now

Check your sources array if not null and add them to previously créated array

```
If( $array1 -ne $null ){ $reference.addrange($array1) 
If($array2 -ne $null) { $diffrence.addrange($array2)
```

Now you are sure that your reference array and diffirence array are not null even they could be empty, and you can securely do comparaison

```
Compare-object -referenceObject $reference -differenceObject $difference
```