# Find out if variable is null or an array containing null variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find out if a variable is null **or** is an array containing null variables.

So for example, a short expression that will match 'false' for each of the following, but 'true' for anything else:

```
$nullvariable = $null
$nullvariable1 = @($null)
$nullvariable2 = @($null, $null)
$nullvariable3 = @("1", $null)
```

Context: I have some Compare-Object calls where I am trying to avoid 'Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null' errors. The first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634900/12872270 works but it's not very legible/comprehensible code.

The remaining answers use an 'if' statement which is more legible, but in my testing Compare-Object doesn't just fail for $null, but also any array *containing* null entries - the given examples using 'if' don't account for that.

Detecting an array containing null variables seems like a separate problem in its own right anyway, hence the question.

Comment: "I am trying to find out if a variable is null or is an array containing null variables." `$null -in $variable` would work for all those examples in your question

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Fab! Never thought of using that. Make it as an answer and I'll happily accept :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon And to be honest I'm not sure I've seen that syntax recommended anywhere, not even in the usually fantastic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null?view=powershell-7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) can evaluate against scalars as well as collections, in this case you can either use `-contains` or `-in` with any of your variables and the result would be `$true`:

```bash
$null -in $nullvariable         # True
$nullvariable1 -contains $null  # True
$null -in $nullvariable2        # True
$nullvariable3 -contains $null  # True
```

Comment: OK, found another scenario where Compare-Object fails - $nullvariable4 = @()
This fails with this check. Any other ideas?